# Testing Password format

Tags: c#, unit-testing, passwords, membership-provider

Ok I am writeing a test for a membership password change. The code below is what I have so far. I need some assistance to check the password format. Min char length is 7 and max length is 8.

Also the I can test if the password format is clear, but how do I test an encrypted format?

Can anyone assist?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestChangePassword()
    {
        try      
        {
            AsaMembershipProvider prov = this.GetMembershipProvider();
            MembershipCreateStatus status;

            //creates user
            MembershipUser user = prov.CreateUser("testUserX", "12345", "test.UserX@abc.com", "", "", true, null, out status);

            //gets user
            user = prov.GetUser("testUserX", false); 
            Assert.AreEqual(user.UserName, "testUserX");

            //Authenticates username and password
            var isAuthenticated = prov.ValidateUser(user.UserName, "12345");
            Assert.IsTrue(isAuthenticated);


            //changes password
            prov.ChangePassword("testUserX",  "12345", "ABCDE");

            //Validates password has been changed
            prov.ValidateUser(user.UserName, "ABCDE");
            Assert.IsTrue(isAuthenticated);

            // Change password back
            prov.ChangePassword("testUserX", "ABCDE", "12345");

            //Validates password has been changed back
            prov.ValidateUser(user.UserName, "12345");


            //Deletes User
            prov.DeleteUser("testUserX", true);
            //tries to get user again
            user = prov.GetUser("testUserX", false);
            //test that no user is returned
            Assert.AreEqual(null, user);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(ex);
            Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Max length 8 for a password? Why would you limit it so?

Comment: You say min length is 7, but then your tests are all fewer than 7 characters.
And as mentioned before, there is absolutely no reason to limit the maximum length of a password. You'll be storing a hash, not the actual password (you are, right?) so you don't even save the miniscule amount of disk space because all your password hashes are the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to write an extension method targeting AsaMembershipProvider which would validate the password and then call ChangePassword from within it to do the actual change

The downside of the approach is that you will have more code to maintain

```
public static class CryptoExtensions {

    public static void ChangePasswordEx(this AsaMembershipProvider mp, string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword){
        // validate format of the password
        if (true /*validation code*/ )
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid password format");
        }

        // rest of the code to encrypt and store the password
        mp.ChangePassword(username, oldPassword, newPassword);
    }

}
```

Your test code should now call **prov.ChangePassword** with **prov.ChangePasswordEx**